# In how many ways 20 persons can enter into 4 queues

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I solved the following question at quiz like this.

While part a) is clear, in part b) I suspect that the idea of choosing students as identical and then ordering them in 20! ways may be wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not your fault, but the word is *queue*.  As for part (b), the answer is correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz I was considering pointing out that spelling correction, but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#Noun) suggests that this is an alternate spelling of "queue" used in South Asia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to (b) is correct. Here is an alternate argument for it that avoids going through the multinomial formula $\binom{4+20-1}{20}$, and arrives at $23!/3!$ directly.

Let's number the students $1$ through $20$, and put them in the cafeteria one at a time - but, in order to be able to get different orders in each line, we will allow ourselves to insert each student in the middle of a queue as well as at the end.

Student $1$ can pick any queue to stand in: there are $4$ options.

Student $2$ can get at the end of any queue, or cut in front of student $1$: that's $5$ options.

Student $3$ can get at the end of any queue, cut in front of student $1$, or cut in front of student $2$: that's $6$ options.

Going on like this, student $k$ can get at the end of one of $4$ queues, or cut in front of one of $k-1$ students, for $k+3$ options total. At the very end, student $20$ will have $23$ options.

Multiplying these together, we have $4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdots 23$,which is $23!/3!$.